# Jquery: Content Rotator / Slider question

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to overhaul a website for a friend of mine at http://gaonlinedriversed.com/

They threw together the current site with Joomla.  You might want to turn your sound off before going to the site, it has a pretty annoying video that starts up, with no option to mute or pause it (one thing I'm fixing).

Anyways, my question:  I believe the site uses MooTools for the content slider on the home page which I'm not familiar with, but I am familiar with Jquery and love it.  I've done various galleries / sliders before, but none of them really recreate the look and usability of the existing site.  Namely, I'm looking for a "slider" that does: A few thumnail photos that change the main content which consist of html content (Picture, Header, Paragraph and button to more content).

I've looked at Coda, Gallery View and few others, but none seem to do exactly what I'm trying to recreate.  Any direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this one on a site of mine, called [anythingslider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/).  I have also checked out one called [easyslider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) too.  If none of those truely fit your need or fancy, I would suggesting finding one that comes close and grab the source and add what you need (assuming the correct licensing).

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the two sliders mentioned above is [Basic jQuery Slider](http://basic-slider.com) - a plugin that I developed. It's designed to support any kind of content and be as simple as possible, making it easy to extend for your specific needs.